# C# Проблема с AIML Bot

Tags: c#, бот

Так работает, и ответы выдаются

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml>
<category>
    <pattern>Hello</pattern>
        <template>
        <random>
            <li>Привет. Нормально.</li>
            <li>Привет. Отлично. Как у тебя?</li>
        </random>
    </template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

Так вместо ответа выдаёт пустую строку.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml>
<category>
    <pattern>Привет</pattern>
        <template>
        <random>
            <li>Привет. Нормально.</li>
            <li>Привет. Отлично. Как у тебя?</li>
        </random>
    </template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе русских букв он так же мог дать ответ?

```
static CuteRobot bot;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //  Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    bot = new CuteRobot();
    string input, output;
    while (true) {
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "quit")
            break;
        output = bot.getOutput(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: А кодировка у вас точно utf-8?

Comment: Да, точно, в NotePad специально преобразовал "принудительно" там уже стояла UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<item name="stripperregex" value="[^0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]"/>
```

`regex` поправить и все будет хорошо.